# error 5764, can´t edit data type of a field in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

im trying to change the type of data of a field in a table on DBeaver but show me and error 
--> [Vertica]VJDBCROLLBACK: Cannot alter the data type of a table column when a node is down <--

the same error is showed when i try to export a table output from Pentaho to my DBeaver table, havings troubles with the format of some files.

the error is pointed to the fields´s format in the export and when i try to change it directly from DBeaver[image: ERROR FROM PENTAHO][image]

Comment: Is there a down node? Check by querying the nodes table. `SELECT * FROM nodes;`

Comment: i realize that ... on my pentaho tranformation i was not reciving data because i had changed a file of foldfer, i refresh the path an everything was okey... zorry for my early post and my fool error. thanks btw